# How to put properties in an array into seperate <p> tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put each property (first name, last name, and credit) into separate p tags inside separate div. I managed to get them into separate divs but still can't seem to get each property in separate p tags instead it looks like this..

My results:

```
JasonVorheesFriday the 13th

FreddyKruegerA Nightmare on Elm Street

RogerRabbitWho Framed Roger Rabbit

KevinMcCallisterHome Alone

GodzillaKing of The MonstersGodzilla

BuzzLightyearToy Story

MarionCobrettiCobra
```

My Code:

```
var people =[
        {first:"Jason", last:"Vorhees", credit:"Friday the 13th"},
        {first:"Freddy", last:"Krueger", credit:"A Nightmare on Elm Street" },
        {first:"Roger", last:"Rabbit", credit:"Who Framed Roger Rabbit" },
        {first:"Kevin", last:"McCallister", credit:"Home Alone" },
        {first:"Godzilla", last:"King of The Monsters", credit:"Godzilla" },
        {first:"Buzz", last:"Lightyear", credit:"Toy Story" },
        {first:"Marion", last:"Cobretti", credit:"Cobra" }
    ]

    var body = document.querySelector('body');

    for(let i=0; i<people.length; i++)
    {
        var tempDiv;
        var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        var first = document.createTextNode(people[i].first);
        var last = document.createTextNode(people[i].last);
        var credit = document.createTextNode(people[i].credit);

        p.appendChild(first);
        p.appendChild(last);
        p.appendChild(credit);
        p.appendChild(tempDiv);
        body.appendChild(tempDiv);
        body.appendChild(p);
        tempDiv.appendChild(p);

    }
```

need names and credits in separate paragraphs for example:

```
Jason
Vorhees
Friday the 13th

Freddy 
Krueger
A Nightmare on Elm Street
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question, not an image of your code.

Comment: Do not post pictures **of** your code and results. .. Please post your code and results into the body of the question.  Many people who want to help, will copy and paste to be able to create a verifiable example.

Comment: [Never post pictures of text when you can post the actual text. Be sure that it is properly formatted and readable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is this any better? Sorry first time posting anything.

Comment: While your example text output is helpful, it would be considerably better for you to show the exact example HTML which you are intending to create.

Answer (score -1):

I would tend to use `String.replace` and `element.innerHTML` for a simple page building routine like this.  Consider the following snippet...

```js
var people = [
    {first:"Jason", last:"Vorhees", credit:"Friday the 13th"},
    {first:"Freddy", last:"Krueger", credit:"A Nightmare on Elm Street" },
    {first:"Roger", last:"Rabbit", credit:"Who Framed Roger Rabbit" },
    {first:"Kevin", last:"McCallister", credit:"Home Alone" },
    {first:"Godzilla", last:"King of The Monsters", credit:"Godzilla" },
    {first:"Buzz", last:"Lightyear", credit:"Toy Story" },
    {first:"Marion", last:"Cobretti", credit:"Cobra" }
];

/* create String templates of HTML-tags */
var div = '<div class="border" id="%%ID%%">%%TXT%%</div>';
var para = "<p>%%TXT%%</p>";
/* variable to hold output String */
var html = "";

/* loop through 'people' array */
people.forEach(function(n, i) {
    /* 'n' = each item in 'people' array
       'i' = index of 'n' */

    /* build paragraphs as Strings
       on temporary variable 'p' */
    let p = para.replace("%%TXT%%", n.first);
    p += para.replace("%%TXT%%", n.last);
    p += para.replace("%%TXT%%", n.credit);

    /* add paragraphs to div */
    html += div.replace("%%TXT%%", p).replace("%%ID%%", i);
});

/* insert 'html' into document body */
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.border {
    padding:0 1em;
    border:1px solid #888;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
.border p:last-of-type {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This String-based approach is sometimes faster and more straightforward that using `document.createElement()` and nesting multiple elements with `element.appendChild()` etc -- although I would use `.appendChild` when adding event functionality to the elements I was creating.

Hope that helps, and please keep the comments regarding a properly formed question in mind if/when you post again - it just means you'll get better answers more quickly.  :D

- [Array.forEach @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [String.replace @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Hmm.  When down voting it's polite to leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: I did not downvote you .. But I will upvote if you can provide a `code snippet` that shows your script is functioning properly.

Comment: @Zak I dance to your tune  ;-)